# How to generate the banana-shaped distribution in r

Tags: r

I want to generate the dataset whose distribution is bivariate (or multivariate) banana-shaped. But, I can`t find the code about it.

Comment: Can you use another fruit analogy? I'm afraid I don't understand what a bivariate banana would look like.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Clearly it would be yellow and curved, and it would have a sweet aroma when ripe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is code which I took verbatim from the `bayesm` [package in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesm/bayesm.pdf):

```
## simulate bivariate data from the "Banana" distribution (Meng and Barnard)
banana=function(A,B,C1,C2,N,keep=10,init=10)
{
    R=init*keep+N*keep
    x1=x2=0
    bimat=matrix(double(2*N),ncol=2)
    for (r in 1:R) {
        x1=rnorm(1,mean=(B*x2+C1)/(A*(x2^2)+1),sd=sqrt(1/(A*(x2^2)+1)))
        x2=rnorm(1,mean=(B*x2+C2)/(A*(x1^2)+1),sd=sqrt(1/(A*(x1^2)+1)))
        if (r>init*keep && r%%keep==0) {
            mkeep=r/keep; bimat[mkeep-init,]=c(x1,x2)
        }
    }

    return(bimat)
}

# usage
set.seed(66)
nvar2=2
A=0.5; B=0; C1=C2=3
y2=banana(A=A,B=B,C1=C1,C2=C2,1000)
```

Please have a look at the documentation which goes on to demonstrate how you can plot this Banana distribution.

Comment: That's a nice one. You should probably add `plot(y2)` and the resulting image too.

Comment: HTML here to save you cut n paste from PDF: http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bayesm/functions/rDPGibbs - I can't find the quoted reference for the "Banana" distribution though.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot !! I will try it :-) 
Thanks again :-0
#Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: There is a typo in your code on the `x2=` line; the mean should use `x1` instead. see the source paper here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/GelmanMeng1991